# Injection of autowired dependencies fails using JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on an application in Spring Boot using Hibernate and JPA to interact with the database. I keep running into problems for one function declared in an interface that extends JpaRepository.

This is what my interface looks like:

```
public interface AlarmRepository extends JpaRepository<Alarm, Long>{
    @Query("select a from Alarm a where a.alnr = :alnr and a.exch = :exch and a.header1 like '%:header1%'")
    Alarm findAlarmByAlnrAndExchAndHeader1(
        @Param("alnr") int alnr, 
        @Param("exch") String exch, 
        @Param("header1") String header1);

    @Query("select a from Alarm a where a.alnr = :alnr and a.exch = :exch and a.alcat = :alcat and a.alcls = :alcls and a.ceased is null")
    Alarm findAlarmByAlnrAndExchAndAlcatAndAlcls(
        @Param("alnr") int alnr, 
        @Param("exch") String exch, 
        @Param("alcat") String alcat,
        @Param("alcls") String alcls);

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Alarm a SET a.ceased = :ceased WHERE a.alnr = :alnr AND a.exch = :exch AND a.alcat = :alcat AND a.alcls = :alcls")
    @Transactional
    int setCeasedTime(
        @Param("ceased") Date ceased,
        @Param("alnr") int alnr, 
        @Param("exch") String exch, 
        @Param("alcat") String alcat,
        @Param("alcls") String alcls);
}
```

**Here is the exception I get**

```
2016-01-11 14:34:51.941 ERROR 7449 --- [           main] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter        : line 1:8: unexpected token: is
2016-01-11 14:34:51.945 ERROR 7449 --- [           main] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter        : line 1:8: unexpected token: is
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: is
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.updateStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:295) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1836) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344) [spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.createQuery(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86) [spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62) [spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72) [spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53) [spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:136) [spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:204) [spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:73) [spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416) [spring-data-commons-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206) [spring-data-commons-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251) [spring-data-commons-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237) [spring-data-commons-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92) [spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838) [spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) [spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at is.siminn.alarm.AlarmApplication.main(AlarmApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]

2016-01-11 14:34:51.948  WARN 7449 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dispatcher': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private is.siminn.alarm.repository.AlarmRepository is.siminn.alarm.Dispatcher.alarmRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'alarmRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract int is.siminn.alarm.repository.AlarmRepository.setCeasedTime(int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)!
>>>> Left out some info message since the message body can't take more than 30.000 characters
2016-01-11 14:34:51.967 ERROR 7449 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dispatcher': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private is.siminn.alarm.repository.AlarmRepository is.siminn.alarm.Dispatcher.alarmRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'alarmRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract int is.siminn.alarm.repository.AlarmRepository.setCeasedTime(int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at is.siminn.alarm.AlarmApplication.main(AlarmApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private is.siminn.alarm.repository.AlarmRepository is.siminn.alarm.Dispatcher.alarmRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'alarmRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract int is.siminn.alarm.repository.AlarmRepository.setCeasedTime(int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'alarmRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract int is.siminn.alarm.repository.AlarmRepository.setCeasedTime(int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract int is.siminn.alarm.repository.AlarmRepository.setCeasedTime(int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:204) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:73) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1836) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

If I omit setCeasedTime in the interface the injection works and the application runs fine.

**Alarm entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ALARM")
public class Alarm implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long id;
    private Integer version;
    private int alnr;
    private String alcls;
    private String alcat;
    private String exch;
    private Date initiated;
    private Date ceased;
    private String header1;
    private String header2;
    private String spr;

    public Alarm() {
        super();
    }

    public Alarm(int alnr, String alcls, String alcat, String exch, Date initiated, Date ceased, String header1,
        String header2, String spr) {
        super();
        this.alnr = alnr;
        this.alcls = alcls;
        this.alcat = alcat;
        this.exch = exch;
        this.initiated = initiated;
        this.ceased = ceased;
        this.header1 = header1;
        this.header2 = header2;
        this.spr = spr;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, scale = 0)
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Column(name="ALNR")
    public int getAlnr() {
        return alnr;
    }

    public void setAlnr(int alnr) {
        this.alnr = alnr;
    }

    @Column(name="ALCLS")
    public String getAlcls() {
        return alcls;
    }

    public void setAlcls(String alcls) {
        this.alcls = alcls;
    }

    @Column(name="ALCAT")
    public String getAlcat() {
        return alcat;
    }

    public void setAlcat(String alcat) {
        this.alcat = alcat;
    }

    @Column(name="EXCH")
    public String getExch() {
        return exch;
    }

    public void setExch(String exch) {
        this.exch = exch;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "INITIATED", length = 6)
    public Date getInitiated() {
        return initiated;
    }

    public void setInitiated(Date initiated) {
        this.initiated = initiated;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "CEASED", length = 6, nullable = true)
    public Date getCeased() {
        return ceased;
    }

    public void setCeased(Date ceased) {
        this.ceased = ceased;
    }

    @Column(name="HEADER1")
    public String getHeader1() {
        return header1;
    }

    public void setHeader1(String header1) {
        this.header1 = header1;
    }

    @Column(name="HEADER2")
    public String getHeader2() {
        return header2;
    }

    public void setHeader2(String header2) {
        this.header2 = header2;
    }

    @Column(name="SPR", length = 4000)
    public String getSpr() {
        return spr;
    }

    public void setSpr(String spr) {
        this.spr = spr;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Alarm entity DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE "ALARM"."ALARM" (
    "ID" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "ALCAT" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
    "ALCLS" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
    "ALNR" NUMBER(10,0),
    "CEASED" TIMESTAMP (6),
    "EXCH" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
    "HEADER1" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
    "HEADER2" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
    "INITIATED" TIMESTAMP (6),
    "SPR" VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),
    "VERSION" NUMBER(10,0),
    PRIMARY KEY ("ID");
```

Am I missing something in my setCeasedTime declaration or am I doing it wrong?

Thanks

I solved the problem by using .saveAndFlush(S entity) from JpaRepository instead of defining my own query in the AlarmRepository interface. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the entity for `Alarm`? Is it matching correctly the DB? What's the DDL for the `alarm` table if such exists?

Comment: @BorisPavlović, I updated my question with the Alarm entity and Alarm DDL.

Comment: Post the full stack trace. Also why are you using a query and not simply update entities? Also your repository declaration is wrong, your id is a `long` not an `int`. So your declaration should be `public interface AlarmRepository extends JpaRepository<Alarm, Long>`.

Comment: Are you sure you passed all parameters to your method? According to the exception trace something either is missing or null

Comment: @JorgeCampos I commented out the call to setCeasedTime but then injection still fails.

Comment: @M.Deinum I changed the declaration like you suggested but still I get the same error.

Comment: If you comment it and the exception is still the same you didn't correct deployed your application.

Comment: @JorgeCampos, I don't understand what you mean by that. Could you please explain it better?

Comment: @JorgeCampos, how come the injection then only fails on this one query not the other two?

Comment: `SYSTIMESTAMP` is a SQL and not a JPQL keyword. Use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead.

Comment: Injection doesn't fail for the query b ut because of the query, an instance cannot be constructed.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I changed my function to take in `Date` instead of using `SYSTIMESTAMP` but no luck.

`@Modifying
 @Query("UPDATE Alarm a SET a.ceased = :ceased WHERE a.alnr = :alnr AND a.exch = :exch AND a.alcat = :alcat AND a.alcls = :alcls")
 @Transactional
 int setCeasedTime(
   @Param("ceased") Date ceased,
   @Param("alnr") int alnr, 
   @Param("exch") String exch, 
   @Param("alcat") String alcat,
   @Param("alcls") String alcls);`

Comment: I solved the problem by using .saveAndFlush(S entity) from JpaRepository instead of defining my own qurey in the AlarmRepository interface. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the package name of your class:

```
is.siminn.alarm.repository.AlarmRepository
```

avoid using reserved words like `is` or `in` in your packages.